# Netbeans build-impl.xml error

Tags: java, netbeans

I was developing a project on netbeans 6.8 and everything was fine, but a week ago, I installed netbeans 7.0 just for a try.

When i opened nb 7.0 my project was listed in 7.0 as well.

Now today, I am trying to compile my project on netbeans 6.8 and it gives me this error.

> nbproject\build-impl.xml:517: copylibs doesn't support the "indexMetaInf" attribute

I guess netbeans 7.0 changed the file.
How can i fix this problem?

Comment: This is so typical of Netbeans - I am having the same issue in 6.7.1 - It is just so full of bugs it is atrocious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i found the solution myself,and wanted to share,
create a new project with netbeans 6.8 and copy its build-impl.xml and replaced my project's build-impl.xml file.

it worked.

Comment: Make sure the project folder has appropriate permissions or run netbeans as admin

Answer (score 6):

An "easier" way to fix this problem is to set your project view to File - then go to the file build-impl.xml  right click it and select clean.
Then shut down the compiler - restart it and clean and build the application.
It sorted the problem out on my compiler.

Answer (score 5):

```
1. Right Mouse click On Libraries
2. Click On Properties
3. Checked Red Color Jar File List
4. Click ON Remove button
5. Exit NetBeans IDE
6. Restart NetBeans
Screenshot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. You have to create a new project with existing source and copy your source-files and import your libraries again in the new project. Finally clean and build the project. If you have projects as libraries you have to do the same with these projects and import them again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the corrupted project.properties (which is used for  project configuration data or settings) file. When I corrected this file, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you got a problem with your build xml file you can clean and build the project. And also you can resolve issues. To do that first right click on the project. There should be item in the menu for resolve issues. From that you can resolve your issues. I used this solution for resolving path errors to my libs.

Answer (score 0):

I have met similar situation before. 
This my solution.
1. Right Mouse click On Project
2. Click On Properties
3. Click On Libraries
4. Click ON Add Project
5. Chose your Project Earth Icon
6. Add Project JAR Files